# Excel: maximum of consecutive occurrences of a value in a row

Tags: excel

I need a formula to calculate the maximum of consecutive occurrences of a value (value searched is 1) in the same row:

For example, for this row:

1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1

The formula result should be 4, since the maximum number of consecutive occurrences of the number 1 is 4.

Is it possible?

Many thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With data in row 1, in **A2** enter:

```
=A1
```

in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(B1=1,1+A2,0)
```

and copy across.  then in another cell enter:

```
=MAX(A2:V2)
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If you wish to avoid the use of a helper column, then consider this *UDF()*:

```
Public Function Consec1(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, r As Range
    x = 0
    y = 0
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value = 1 Then
            x = x + 1
        Else
            If x > y Then
                y = x
            End If
            x = 0
        End If
    Next r
        Consec1 = y
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I found also a formula 

=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:AH1=1;COLUMN(A1:V1));IF(A1:V1<>1;COLUMN(A1:V1))))

as array formula (Ctrl + Shift + Enter)